# XSLT 1.0 count and then copy structure where child ends-with

Tags: xslt

I have to copy all the sets where the mail end with "test.com", if there count is greater than 5. I've tried several things, but nothing seems to work.

How can I do this with xslt 1.0?

```
<root>
    <sets>
        <set>
            <mail>a@test.com</mail>
            <foo/>
        </set>
        <set>
            <mail>a@test.net</mail>
            <foo/>
        </set>
        <set>
            <mail>b@test.com</mail>
            <foo/>
        </set>
    </sets>
</root>
```

For example I tried this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="count(/root/sets/set[mail = '*test.com'])">
        <root>
            <sets>
                <xsl:for-each select="/root/sets/set">
                    <xsl:if test="contains(./mail, 'test.com')">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="./*"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </sets>
        </root>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you show the XSLT you have currently tried, as it is easier to fix an existing XSLT than write one from scratch? Also, can you show the exact output you want for your current XML. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to copy all the sets where the mail end with "test.com".

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sets">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="set[substring-after(mail, '@')='test.com']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: hi michael, sorry I forgot the requirement of counting the elements first.

Comment: got it working by replacing my if test with your select `count(//set[substring-after(mail, '@')='test.com']) > 5`. Maybe could you show how could I do this with your solution?

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question and post an example showing the exact result you expect to get in each case (i.e. if the count is > 5 and if it isn't?

Comment: I do not understand, how it is working, but it works and you got my vote

Comment: Your result is correct, and on the other case, an empty list is fine.